# Change main window title to that of iframe title

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, node-webkit

I am building a node webkit application and I would like my window title to be same as that of the title of the iframe. My iframe title keeps changing regularly (on receiving a notification). I would like my main window title also to keep track of that change and update its own title.

I extract the title of the iframe with this command with Jquery: 
`$("#app").contents().find("title").text()` where #app is the ID of the iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
newTitleListener = SetInterval(CheckForNewTitle, 200)

oldTitle = '';
function CheckForNewTitle(){
    newTitle = $("#app").contents().find("title").text();
    if (newTitle != oldTitle){ //Set the new title
        document.title = newTitle;
        oldTitle = newTitle;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this won't get updated everytime the title of the iframe changes

Comment: See the changes. Can you access your iframe script? If you can, adding the line suggested by Sourabh would be most efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

it is as simple as putting the below code in your iframe

```
window.parent.document.title = "My new title";
```